# automatic append subgroups joomla

Tags: php, joomla, components, usergroups

I'm recently started with making an own component in Joomla (3.x).
And now i'm trying to automatically append subgroups to a new usergroup.

What i want is the following:
--> When i create a new usergroup A, i want to automatically add subgroup B, subgroup C and subgroup D to usergroup A. (something like a `OnAfterSave`?)

In `/libraries/joomla/table/usergroup.php` i found a function that rebuild the `lft` & `rgt` values for me. Maybe i can do something with that?
Or should i just build the query by myself?

And I don't know where to build the selfmade `onAfterSave` function, which makes the subgroups...

I hope anybody can help me with this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OnAfterXXXXSave()` are Joomla events that are handled by area specific [plugins](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin).

You can either write a plugin to respond to [standard Joomla events](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events) or you can [add support for plugins to a component](http://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_plugins_in_your_component) you've written.

As you can see from that list there is no event associated with `com_categories` however spelunking the `/administrator/com_categories` directory I can see that `category.php` triggers `onContentBeforeSave()` and `onContentAfterSave()` in the `save()` of `CategoriesModelCategory` (i.e. `models/category.php`).

```php
class CategoriesModelCategory extends JModelAdmin
{
:
    public function save($data)
    {
        $dispatcher = JEventDispatcher::getInstance();
    :
    // Trigger the onContentBeforeSave event.
    $result = $dispatcher->trigger($this->event_before_save, array($this->option . '.' . $this->name, &$table, $isNew));
    :
    :
    // Trigger the onContentAfterSave event.
    $dispatcher->trigger($this->event_after_save, array($this->option . '.' . $this->name, &$table, $isNew));
```

Based on that, I would start with a [content plugin (tutorial)](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/Content#onContentPrepare) and adapt it to your use case.

Comment: Thanks, that works. I found the onUserAfterSaveGroup($context, $row, $isNew) method. With this method i was able to create a plugin that automatically adds subgroups to my newly added usergroup.